# Pytorch to ONNX conversion error DeeplabV3

Tags: pytorch, onnx

I'm trying to convert a Pytorch model to ONNX usin this code:

```
import onnx
import torch
import onnxruntime
import numpy as np

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


batch_size = 1
model = torch.jit.load('../saved_weights/model.pt')

x = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224, requires_grad=True)
x = x.to(device)
torch_out = model(x)
torch_out = torch_out['out']


torch.onnx.export(model, x, "../saved_weights/model.onnx",
              export_params=True,
              opset_version=12,
              do_constant_folding=True,
              input_names=['input'],
              output_names=['out'],
              dynamic_axes={ 'input': {0 : 'batch_size'},
                            'output': {0 : 'batch_size'}})
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
 raise errors.UnsupportedOperatorError(
 torch.onnx.errors.UnsupportedOperatorError: Exporting the operator 
 'aten::dict' to ONNX opset version 12 is not supported.
```

I'm not sure why, but could it be that the model output is in the form of a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Referring [Pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html#list-of-supported-operators), you can try:

1. Change the model to not use that operator (here, dictionary).
2. Create a symbolic function to convert the operator and register it as a custom symbolic function.
3. Contribute to PyTorch to add the same symbolic function to torch.onnx itself.

My recommendation is to change the output type to a tensor.

Also, you can visit [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx_supported_aten_ops.html) and check supported operators.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had to save the model using `model.save` instead of a scripted model:

```
model_scripted = torch.jit.script(model) # Export to TorchScript
model_scripted.save('model_scripted.pt') # Save
```